# Text overlapping in Eclipse preferences?

Tags: eclipse, preferences

I was investigating Eclipse's Preferences windows, and I came upon the Formatter options. I decided to have a look, and eventually to create my own format options. Upon clicking the "New" button and selecting a base to work from, It came up with this:

[image: overlapping text]

Does anyone know why this is happening? Or how I can possibly fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but it looks like a GTK-theme.
If so, have you tried a default-theme?

Comment: I haven't thought of that... I'll try it now.

Comment: Resetting to the default theme fixed it. Thank you :)